# When authorize, the link to the login page does not have an admin area in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have login code like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login() => View(new LoginVM());
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM loginVM)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
         return View(loginVM);

    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginVM.UserNameOrEmail) 
            ?? await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginVM.UserNameOrEmail);

    if (user != null)
    {
        var passwordCheck = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginVM.Password);

        if (passwordCheck)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginVM.Password, false, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        TempData["Error"] = "Bạn đã nhập sai mật khẩu, vui lòng thử lại!!!";

        return View(loginVM);
    }

    TempData["Error"] = "Không có email hoặc username này trong hệ thống!!!";

    return View(loginVM);
}
```

How to fix this?

I registered the area for the controller but when I access it, the login link is

```
https://localhost:44329/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:44329/Admin/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin
```

Comment: Could you post controller attribute code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jerry The attributes OP is using are built in, no need for that.

Comment: Post your Authentication/Identity registration code from program.cs or startup.cs.